# JQuery attribute loop

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a JQuery script which gives me a bootstrap popover image when ik click on a link. The popover works, i get a beautiful image, but i have many records and it keeps giving me the same picture over and over.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

**HTML**:

```html
<td><a class='smoel_opvragen test' id='resources/img/smoelenboek/1.jpg' target='_blank'>Surname, Firstname</a></td>
<td><a class='smoel_opvragen test' id='resources/img/smoelenboek/3.jpg' target='_blank'>Surname, Firstname</a></td>
<td><a class='smoel_opvragen test' id='resources/img/smoelenboek/4.jpg' target='_blank'>Surname, Firstname</a></td>
<td><a class='smoel_opvragen test' id='resources/img/smoelenboek/5.jpg' target='_blank'>Surname, Firstname</a></td>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
$(function () {
    $(".test").popover({
        title: 'Profielfoto',
        content: "<img src='" + $(".smoel_opvragen").attr("id") + "' width='150px'>",
        html: true
    })
});
```

Comment: You're attempting to query for an element that does not exist yet. Move your script to the bottom of the body.

Comment: You have many links of the same class?

Comment: I have, the JQuery script is in the footer.

Comment: Should the popover appear on click? As you have it, it would appear to load a popover for each .test on document load. It seems you need a click event handler for each link. Added an answer.

Comment: Yes, it should, and that works just fine, it's just the loop of the pics...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to iterate the items since the config depends on the item:

```
$(".test").each(function () {
    $(this).popover({
        title: 'Profielfoto',
        content: "<img src='" + this.id + "' width='150px'>",
        html: true
    });
});
```

Additionally, the `id` is an odd place to store the url. I would use a `data-` attribute like `data-image-url`.